# TypeScript Overload with different return types

Tags: typescript, monads

As an exercise, I’m trying to reimplement the `Maybe` pattern from Haskell-like languages into TypeScript. So far so well, I got a satisfying result, and it’s working great, with some type checking stuff that I had to override by hand.
I would like to be a little bit more JavaScript-ish and I try to define a function map which can return both pure data or Promise of data.

Here's some code to be more clear:

```
class Maybe<A> {
  #value: A | null

  private constructor(value: A) {
    this.#value = value
  }

  static just<A>(value: A): Maybe<A> {
    return new Maybe(value)
  }

  static nothing<A>(): Maybe<A> {
    return <Maybe<A>>(<unknown>new Maybe(null))
  }

  static nullable<A>(value: A | null): Maybe<A> {
    if (value) {
      return this.just(value)
    } else {
      return this.nothing()
    }
  }

  value(): A {
    if (this.#value) {
      return this.#value
    } else {
      throw new Error('Maybe has no data')
    }
  }

  map<B>(mapper: (a: A) => Promise<B>): Promise<Maybe<B>> // I got an error here in the overloading
  map<B>(mapper: (a: A) => B): Maybe<B> {
    if (this.#value) {
      const result = mapper(this.#value)
      if (result instanceof Promise) {
        return result.then((e: B) => Maybe.just(e))
      } else {
        return new Maybe(mapper(this.#value))
      }
    } else {
      return Maybe.nothing()
    }
  }
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to define the map function as defined above?

Comment: What error? Also, given that B could already be a promise, why do you need the overload?

Comment: `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.` Because when you’re dealing with async and Maybe, I find better to provide a `Promise<Maybe>` instead of `Maybe<Promise>` (which is quite similar in the code), but the first allows you to use await and to continue Maybe-chains naturally, and not having to deal with Promise in your `Maybe.map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like these, look at the comments

```
class Maybe<A> {
  #value: A | null

  // altered argument here
  private constructor(value: A | null) {
    this.#value = value
  }

  static just<A>(value: A): Maybe<A> {
    return new Maybe(value)
  }

  static nothing<A>(): Maybe<A> {
    // omitted casts
    return new Maybe<A>(null);
  }

  static nullable<A>(value: A | null): Maybe<A> {
    if (value) {
      return this.just(value)
    } else {
      return this.nothing()
    }
  }

  value(): A {
    if (this.#value) {
      return this.#value
    } else {
      throw new Error('Maybe has no data')
    }
  }

  // added two separate declarations
  map<B>(mapper: (a: A) => Promise<B>): Promise<Maybe<B>>;
  map<B>(mapper: (a: A) => B): Maybe<B>;

  // and single implementation which fits both declarations
  map<B>(mapper: (a: A) => B | Promise<B>): Maybe<B> | Promise<Maybe<B>> {
    if (this.#value) {
      const result = mapper(this.#value)
      if (result instanceof Promise) {
        return result.then((e: B) => Maybe.just(e))
      } else {
        return new Maybe(result)
      }
    } else {
      return Maybe.nothing()
    }
  }
}
```

So now `Maybe.just(0).map(x=>x+1)` is `Maybe<number>` but `Maybe.just(0).map(x=>Promise.resolve(x+1))` is `Promise<Maybe<number>>`

However for `Maybe.nothing().map(x=>Promise.resolve(x+1))` you'll receive `Maybe<number>` while interface will declare `Promies<Maybe<number>>` so it's not a good idea, since you can't tell function return type in runtime without calling it

Comment: Hum… Yes, I see your point. In my first implementation, I ended up with two functions, one `map` and one `asyncMap`, so in the second case, I always had a Promise resulting. But here we can’t determine at compile-time to call two different functions even if the type of argument is not the same, right?

Comment: Unfortunately we can’t. Typescript does not provide context/type aware transformations